# Voice channel deletion after a few seconds when user leave it doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I have a command that creates a voice channel, and if this channel is empty, it will be deleted after 3 seconds. So if I created the channel and nobody join it everything will be fine, but if someone is in the channel longer than 3s and after leaves, then it won't be deleted. I think the problem is somewhere here (in the code below), but I don't know how to fix it, is there any possible ways how to fix it?

```
bot.on(`voiceStateUpdate`, oldMember => {
        deleteEmptyChannelAfterDelay(oldMember.voiceChannel);


    });

    function deleteEmptyChannelAfterDelay(voiceChannel, delayMS = 3000){
        if(!voiceChannel) return;
        if(voiceChannel.members.first()) return;
        if(!voiceChannel.health) voiceChannel.health = 0;
        voiceChannel.health += 1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!voiceChannel) return;
            if(voiceChannel.members.first()) return;
            voiceChannel.health -= 1;
            if(voiceChannel.health > 0) return;
            voiceChannel.delete()
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }, delayMS);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error message or something?

Comment: `(node:14436) DeprecationWarning: Guild#createChannel: Create channels with an options object instead of separate parameters` That's all it writes

Comment: It's not related to that problem it means that you are creating a voice channel in separate parameters